# Create gradient with transparent edge

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending

I am trying to create a linear gradient with a transparent edge.

I am hoping to use blending options in photoshop, so that I can fine-tune my results. The issue is, that it seems I would have to use blending modes to get my results. The issue with blending modes is that they introduce a transparency effect (multiply).  I hope to achieve my results with opaque colors and the shapes tools. I'd rather not use the gradient tool because results are not editable without recreating the gradient from scratch essentially.

Here is the effect I am going for!

[image: Results wanted]

Comment: For what purpose? If it's for something like a web page background, you could use a CSS3 gradient to lie on top of the background image.

Comment: You're right I could do it in CSS3. I thought about doing that. Though I want IE8+ support, so I need to make a proper tile.  Also part of me wants to know how to do it editable for my design fine-tuning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite certain I understand, but... couldn't you simply use a Gradient Fill layer? `Layer > New Fill Layer > Gradient...`

[image]

That gives you the ability to adjust the gradient dynamically, without being restricted to the Layer Style limitations or using blend modes.

Comment: That works. I knew there had to be a way to have editable gradients without shapes layer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about you apply a layer effect to your foreground shape?

Outer or inner glow set to the dark color would do the trick and be completely editable. Inner shadow or drop shadow could also work if you prefer.

Comment: glow limitations are 250px, and then you're kind using a mask to crop the opposite edges. I don't think it's possible to have a transparent shape.

Comment: @jnollette you *can* have a transparent shape. Set the layer **Fill Opacity to 0%** but leave the **Opacity** at 100%.